# Remover un dato de una lista

Tags: python, lista

¿Cómo podría eliminar un dato de una lista en python?, si tengo:

```
a = [
        ['10', '225', 'universidad', '5'],
        ['11', '555', 'colegio', '7'],
        ['12', '225', 'escuela', '9']
]
```

Y quiero eliminar toda la lista que está repitiendo el 225, busco eliminar

```
['12','225','escuela','9']
```

y que retorne:

```
b = [
        ['10', '225', 'universidad', '5'],
        ['11', '555', 'colegio', '7']
]
```

He intentado usar

```
for item in a:
 if item not in a[1]:
    b+=item
print(item)
```

Comment: Ojo, `item` en el primer `for` es una lista, por lo que en la segunda línea revisas si una lista se encuentra en la segunda lista de `a` (`['11', '555', 'colegio', '7']`) pero como solo son strings, siempre el resultado de ese if va a ser `True`. Por último cambia ese `b+=item` por un `b.append(item)` para que así `b` sea una lista de listas. Te serviría si cambias de orden `item` por `a[0][1]` en el `if` pero no resuelve el hecho  que va a eliminar todas las ocurrencias de 225 cuando, por lo visto, debes conservar la primera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La comparación es incorrecta:

```
if item not in a[1]:
```

`item` es una sublista de `a` (fila) y `a[1]` es siempre la segunda sublista (fila)  no la segunda columna. Para ver si ya existe el item en `b` debes iterar sobre `b` con un `for` anidado:

```
a = [
     ['10', '225', 'universidad', '5'],
     ['11', '555', 'colegio', '7'],
     ['12', '225', 'escuela', '9']
]

b = []
for a_item in a:
    value = a_item[1]
    for b_item in b:
        if value == b_item[1]:
            break
    else:
        b.append(a_item)
```

ésto no obstante es muy ineficiente si tu lista es medianamente grande dado que hay que iterar sobre `b` (en el peor de los casos al completo) por cada item de `a`.

Una forma eficiente de remover los duplicados es usar un conjunto como apoyo para tener controlados que valores de la segunda columna existen ya en la lista `b`:

```
a = [
     ['10', '225', 'universidad', '5'],
     ['11', '555', 'colegio', '7'],
     ['12', '225', 'escuela', '9']
]

b = []

aux = set()
for item in a:
    value = item[1]
    if value not in aux:
        aux.add(value)
        b.append(item)
```

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
b = []

aux = set()
for item in a:
    if (value:= item[1]) not in aux:
        aux.add(value)
        b.append(item)
```

Incluso se puede hacer uso de compresión de listas, aunque de forma algo "torticera":

```
aux = set()
b = [item for item in a if item[1] not in aux and not aux.add(item[1])]
```

**`Python >= 3.8`**

```
aux = set()
b = [item for item in a if (value:= item[1]) not in aux and not aux.add(value)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres eliminar el '225', fijo, excepto la primera ocurrencia, entonces te puede servir algo así.

```
first = True
b = []
for item in a:
    found = '225' in item
    if found and first:
        first = False
    elif found and not first:
        continue
    b.append(item)
```

Por cada elemento de la lista principal, se obtiene una sublista, item. Se almacena en `found` si el '225' se encuentra dentro de la lista. Si se encuentra y es la primera vez que ocurre, entonces se cambia a `first = False`, y el ciclo llega a la línea final añadiendo `item` a la lista `b`.
Si vuelve a suceder otra ocurrencia, entrará en el `elif` con un `continue` lo que evitará que ejecute la última linea, omitiendo esa sublista en b. 
Si no existe '225' entonces no entra a ninguno de los dos `if`, por lo que se va directo a la última linea haciendo el `append()`.